# 74HCT245 buffer IC

Tags: buffer

In 74HCT245 bidirectional buffer IC, 3rd state is high impedance state as shown below.

[image: 74HCT245]

Link for datasheet: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT245.pdf

If we want 3rd state as "Latch" ( to hold previous value ), Is there any option ( IC ) available for such application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For a latching function take a look at the 74HCT373. This will only be a one direction part.

For a bi-directional part that has registers in both directions take a look at the 74HCT646.

Comment: May I also suggest the 74HCT374 and the 74HCT377, other latches but with slightly different clock/enable inputs.